# Calling C# Class method from AngularJs bound object

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, razor

sorta new with Angular, odds are I can't do it... However,

What I'm trying to do is take a button and use the click event to call the bound objects codebehind method (without use of javascript functions):

i.e.: ng-click="MyClassObject.Method(param)"

Is this possible? and if so, what am I missing? :/

Note the object is bound, and data members are being used elsewhere in the view..

Comment: You will need javascript to do it.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured.. :/ Thanks you much